# How to use Line Renderer to plot Line chart/graph?

Tags: unity-game-engine, linechart, linegraph

I was told that to create a line chart/graph, I need to first know how to create graphics like line into the game scene. I did and now how should I go about plotting and making it into a line chart? I need to plot a real-time graph.
This is the code for drawing line using Line renderer.

```
public Transform origin;
    public Transform destination;


    public float lineDrawSpeed = 6f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, origin.position);

        lineRenderer.SetWidth(.10f, .10f);

        dist = Vector3.Distance (origin.position, destination.position);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (counter < dist) {

        counter += .1f / lineDrawSpeed;

        float x = Mathf.Lerp (0, dist, counter);

        Vector3 pointA = origin.position;
        Vector3 pointB = destination.position;

        //Get the unit vector in the desired direction, multiply by the desired length and add the starting point.
        Vector3 pointAlongLine = x * Vector3.Normalize (pointB - pointA) + pointA;

        lineRenderer.SetPosition (1, pointAlongLine);

}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your effort? So that we can guide you about the problems you might be facing..

Comment: The best way to get the question reopened is to click "edit" and add relevant source code and output (if any).

Comment: I have inserted the codes above.

Comment: It seems that all you need to do is to draw all other lines. The question "how to create a line chart" is really vague, so we can't be sure what exactly are you trying to do here.

Comment: I need to plot the line chart as well. After the other lines are drawn, how do I actually plot it? With the coordinates (x,y)